# Create accordian in a table row in React

Tags: reactjs, accordion

I am trying to display the the json child data which is a list as accordian, i.e when I click parent data all child data should be displayed.

```
<div className="container" style={{ marginTop: '20px', width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
  {
    result.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <table key={index} style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
            <tr style={{ height: '50px' }}>
              <td>DB Response</td>
              <td>{item.db_response.total_db_time} ms</td>
              <item.db_response.db_proc_list> => display this as accordian
            </tr>
            <tr style={{ height: '50px' }}>
              <td>File Op Response</td>
              <td>{item.file_op_response.total_time} ms</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </>
      );
    })
  }
</div>
```

item.db_response.db_proc_list contains the list of json, which I want to render when I click on 'DB Response' row.

Can anyone help me build this ?